# Keyboard shortcut to activate overlay "Replace" widget in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, find-replace

In VSCode, `Ctrl+F` activates a little "overlay" Find window that searches for a string in the current editor.

`Edit --> Replace` activates a similar overlay Replace window.

**Is there a keyboard shortcut to activate this overlay Replace window, or can one be configured?**

I went to `Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts` and searched for "replace", but the Replace action mentioned there (`Ctrl+H`) does something different: it opens a sidebar which can do find/replace in the entire workspace. I don't see any other actions there that activate the overlay Replace window.

Comment: That "Replace` widget you refer to is just the same "Find" widget with the `replace` input box already opened up for you.  It only finds and replaces in the current file.  There is no separate floating `Search` widget - only the panel version you have seen.

Comment: @Mark Sure. My question remains though: can I configure a single shortcut to activate "the find widget with the replace input box already opened up"?

Comment: Okay, but Ctrl+H does exactly what you want - opens the find in current file widget with the replace input box opened.  Ctrl+Shift+H opens the Search in all files panel with the replace field opened.  You have different behaviour than that?

Comment: @Mark The sidebar takes up precious vertical space compared to an overlay window. I have two editors side by side, if the sidebar is also opened the editors windows are too narrow to read the code effectively.

Comment: Did you try to put the search function into the bottom panel (where the terminal lives) if you need the horizontal space?

Comment: in MacOS the Ctrl+H is Delete Character?!